# Jquery tab onload hide

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I have three tabs in jquery to show and hide. The scenario is that when the page is loaded, all the three tabs are showing at the same time. But when I click on the second tab, the other two tabs gets hided exactly the same way I want. I want when the page is loaded, only first tab should be shown and other two tabs should not be shown. Please see the code for your reference:-

javascript code:-

```
<script src='assets/js/swipe.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
       startSlide: 4,
       auto: 3000,
       continuous: true,
       disableScroll: true,
       stopPropagation: true,
       callback: function(index, element) {},
       transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
    });

    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe1');
    window.mySwipe1 = Swipe(elem, {
      startSlide: 4,
       auto: 3000,
       continuous: true,
       disableScroll: true,
       stopPropagation: true,
       callback: function(index, element) {},
       transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
    });

    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe2');
    window.mySwipe2 = Swipe(elem, {
      startSlide: 4,
       auto: 3000,
       continuous: true,
       disableScroll: true,
       stopPropagation: true,
       callback: function(index, element) {},
       transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
        });
```

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#services" data-toggle="tab">Interiors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#products" data-toggle="tab">Culture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#products1" data-toggle="tab">CSR</a></li>
</ul>
```

HTML for the tab.

```
<div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active service-detail01" id="services">
                <div class="container-fluid margin-bottom-50 clearfix" style="padding-left: 0px">
               <div class="span4">
                    <!--<div class="service-img"><img src="assets/images/bs-pg/service-dummy-img.jpg" /></div>-->


                    <div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
                        <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                            <div><b><img  src="assets/images/interiors/Career-Images.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/interiors/Monitoring_Live-Monitoring-Station-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/interiors/Monitoring_The-Active-Deterrence-Station-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/interiors/Monitoring_The-Command-and-Control-Center-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/interiors/Ther-Corporate-Office-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/interiors/The-Securens-Lobby-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img src="assets/images/interiors/The-Support-Department-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/interiors/Training-Room.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
                        <button onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button> 
                        <button onclick='mySwipe.next()'>next</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="span4">
                    <h3 style="line-height:16px; height:50px;">Celebrations</h3>
                    <p>Securens celebrates festivals and other special occasions with Fun and Frolic.</p>

                </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane active service-detail01" id="products">
                <div class="container-fluid margin-bottom-50 clearfix" style="padding-left: 0px">
               <div class="span4">

                    <div id='mySwipe1' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
                        <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                            <div><b><img  src="assets/images/culture/Core-Group-Meeting-in-Progress.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/culture/HR-Meeting-in-Progress-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/culture/Team-Securens-Mixed-Team-1-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/culture/Team-Securens-Team-3-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/culture/The-Football-Cafe-as-Smart-Object-1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
                        <button onclick='mySwipe1.prev()'>prev</button> 
                        <button onclick='mySwipe1.next()'>next</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="span4">
                    <h3 style="line-height:16px; height:50px;">Culture</h3>

                    <p>We believe in thriving in a fun and producing atmosphere.</p>

                </div>

                </div>
            </div>


              <div class="tab-pane active service-detail01" id="products1">
                <div class="container-fluid margin-bottom-50 clearfix" style="padding-left: 0px">
               <div class="span4">
                    <!--<div class="service-img"><img src="assets/images/bs-pg/service-dummy-img.jpg" /></div>-->


                    <div id='mySwipe2' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
                        <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                            <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Banglore.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Chennai.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Delhi.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Delhi-2.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Kolkatta.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                         <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Mumbai1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                         <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Mumbai2.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                         <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Mumbai3.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                          <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Mumbai4.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                           <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Pune1.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                           <div><b><img  src="assets/images/CSR/Pune2.jpg" alt="Securens" title="Securens"></b></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
                        <button onclick='mySwipe2.prev()'>prev</button> 
                        <button onclick='mySwipe2.next()'>next</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="span4">
                     <!--<div class="service-img"><img src="assets/images/bs-pg/service-dummy-img.jpg" /></div>-->
                    <h3 style="line-height:16px; height:50px;">CSR</h3>

                    <p>Our teams are about enthusiastic about Social Responsibility Initiatives.</p>

                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery hide and show events directly on document ready event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab-pane").hide();
    $("#services).show();
});
```

Also bind onclick Events on each list item to show the corresponding tab as:

```
function showTab(tabName){
  $(".tab-pane").hide();
  $("#"+tabName).show();
}
```

Or bind it directly in document event for on-click event on each list -item

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab-pane").hide();
    $("#services").show();

    $("#first_li").click(function(){
          showTab('services');
    });
    $("#second_li").click(function(){
          showTab('products');
    });
    $("#third_li").click(function(){
          showTab('products1');
    });
});
```

And name the list items as :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs">
    <li class="active" id="first_li"><a href="#services" data-toggle="tab">Interiors</a></li>
    <li id="second_li"><a href="#products" data-toggle="tab">Culture</a></li>
    <li id="third_li"><a href="#products1" data-toggle="tab">CSR</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi akash, can you please write the code for the same, as I am bit confused

Comment: i tried it with your code,but onload the whole tab is hided, and on second and third tab also it is not showing.

Comment: still not working on the page load, working fine on second and tab click

Comment: hi akash, my code in the question which is of javascript needs to be there with all the other things. I think that is why it is not working

Comment: Yes that might be the reason, else the last fiddle was working fine(showing first tab on page load and rest on event click)

Comment: akash, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/96vrz2dp/2/. As Der did it, it is working fine for me, but the problem is that, I cant see the images when I click on second and third tab. Please help with this

Comment: Try removing the display:none from both the tabs(#product and #product1), this inline css property is preventing it from rendering

Comment: How are you hiding the tabs on page load? Since you have removed the display:none part from the inline css you have to opt for some method to hide those tabs on page load. Try using the code i mentioned in the first section

Comment: I tried your first section code, but it was not working.I am not talking about the hiding tabs. Actually what I want is that on page load u can see the other two tab sections which is not hiding. I want to hide that two section on page load.The click of the tab is working properly

Comment: Please add your latest fiddle. Only a document ready event was required as per your last update.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab-pane").hide();
    $("#services).show();
});

Comment: In your example the buttons of previous and next is not working, when i clicked on Culture tab and CSR tab

Comment: onDomReady means? how should I do that ? because I implemented the same but still on page load I was able to see the three tabs images. I m thinking i m missing something what is onDomReady

Answer (score 0):

What about simply adding some

```
style="display: none;"
```

to the second and third tab?

And on swipe remove that style.

Or put a "hidden" class to the tabs with the wanted style and toggle this class on swipe.

EDIT:

May not be the best solution, but works for the first...

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#services" data-toggle="tab" onclick="jQuery('.tab-pane').hide(); jQuery('#services').show();">Interiors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products" data-toggle="tab" onclick="jQuery('.tab-pane').hide(); jQuery('#products').show();">Culture</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products1" data-toggle="tab" onclick="jQuery('.tab-pane').hide(); jQuery('#products1').show();">CSR</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I did and styled the div as display:none, can you give help me how to remove that style on swipe ?

Comment: For further help a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the ressources and code would be great.

Comment: Your fiddle needs the path to your swipe.js file... without there is no possibility to check the javascript, because it errors. I dont have the time to search it by myself...

Comment: added the code for swipe.js, please see the updated js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/96vrz2dp/1/

Comment: Look this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96vrz2dp/2/). Sorry, got to work now, cannot do more than sharing this.

Comment: the images for the second and third is not visible.